# Do the items change regularly?

Tags: pokemon-diamond-pearl-platinum

There was an exclusive feature to Pokemon Pearl/Diamond with the DS Wireless Communications. At one point in the game (I have Pokemon Pearl, just to let you all know), a man gives you a kit which lets you go into an underground tunnel. From there, you can dig a **base**. In addition to this, if you go on a stroll through the tunnels, you will meet some vendors. In exchange for a sphere of the right size, you can get an item to decorate your base.

So, the last time I played was about two months ago. Yesterday, I got bored so I started playing it. The problem is, I forgot what the vendors were selling the last time I played. So, my question is, do the items that the vendors are selling change on a regular basis? Thanks in advance.

Comment: If anyone feels the necessity to fix the tags, go ahead. I am not sure what kind of tag belongs to this question.

Comment: Guide to tagging Pokemon questions: http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/6957/pokemon-tag-problems-gotta-tag-em-all/6958#6958

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the vendors change their inventory each day, as well as the prices on individual items. This is mostly from personal experience, but due to the time since I last played Gen4, backed up by the [Bulbapedia entry on The Underground](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/The_Underground#Vendors).

The top of the article also has a handy map that shows where the different types of vendors hang out;

> In the map of the underground at the top of the page, the yellow dots are the trap vendors, the red dots are the treasure vendors, and the blue dots are the goods vendors.